# Is SFTP with password-only client authentication still encrypted?

Tags: sftp

We are setting up a link to a client and they wish to use SFTP but without using keys for client authentication, just passwords. Do you still get the benefit of data encryption with this setup? I thought the protocol used the client keys for encryption but does it or can it use the host key instead?

EDIT:
Looks like Wikipedia has what I needed to know: "SSH also supports password-based authentication that is encrypted by automatically generated keys." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Key_management). And yes not entirely a programming question but a bit of a reflex reaction for me to ask other developers.

Comment: You might have better luck with this question on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There's a difference between the transport-layer key exchange and the user-authentication key exchange. You do not need to generate any client key pairs for password authentication; authentication happens over an encrypted tunnel negotiated by the transport-layer key exchange, which is largely transparent to the user.